# Select from multiple tables with group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these table in my database :

```
Ticket 
 -------------------------------
|ID        int              PK  |
|Paid      varchar(50)          |
 -------------------------------

TicketRow
 ----------------------------------
|ID            int              PK |
|TicketID_FK   int                 |
|SHtimeID_FK   int                 |
 ----------------------------------
```

I want to fetch the duplicated rows, that have same `SHTiemID_FK` and have `Paid='ok'` state in Ticket table, from TicketRow table.
I try this :

```
select SHtimeID_FK,count(*) as cnt from dbo.TicketRow
group by SHtimeID_FK
having count(*)>1
```

But i don't know how should i add Ticket table in my result set.

UPDATE : 
I also need Ticket.ID in my resultset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your scenario correctly you can simply join these two tables by a inner join as I suppose TicketRow.TicketID_FK is a foreign key to Ticket table.

```
select SHtimeID_FK,count(*) as cnt 
from dbo.TicketRow as tr inner join dbo.Ticket as t on tr.TicketID_FK=t.ID
where t.Paid='ok'
group by SHtimeID_FK
having count(*)>1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your solution is correct but i need to add Ticket.ID to my result set, what should i do?

Comment: @SamanGholami, if you group by SHtimeID_FK, you cannot add the Ticket.ID in the select clause because there may be different Ticket.ID in the group. One way is that you also add the Ticket.ID in the group by clause but that changes your business logic isn't it?